# Multiple User Agents in Robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

In robots.txt file I have following sections

```
User-Agent: Bot1
Disallow: /A

User-Agent: Bot2
Disallow: /B

User-Agent: *
Disallow: /C
```

Will statement `Disallow:c` be visible to Bot1 & Bot2 ?

Comment: first google result: "multiple User agents robots.txt" http://wordpress.org/support/topic/robotstxt-multiple-user-agent-lines

Comment: @MarcDefiant Isnt that result the opposite of what is being asked here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr:** No, Bot1 and Bot2 will happily crawl paths starting with `C`.

Each bot only ever complies to at most [a single record (block)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661543/1591669).

#### Original spec

In the [original specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) it says:

> If the value is '*', the record describes the default access policy for any robot that has not matched any of the other records.

#### Expired RFC draft

The original spec, including some additions (like `Allow`) became a draft for RFC, but never got accepted/published. In [3.2.1 The User-agent line](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) it says:

> The robot must obey the first record in /robots.txt that contains a User-Agent line whose value contains the name token of the robot as a substring. The name comparisons are case-insensitive. If no such record exists, it should obey the first record with a User-agent line with a "*" value, if present. If no record satisfied either condition, or no records are present at all, access is unlimited.

So it confirms the interpretation of the original spec.

#### Implementations

Google, for example, [gives an example](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) that seems to follow the spec:

> Each section in the robots.txt file is separate and does not build upon previous sections. For example:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /folder1/
>
> User-Agent: Googlebot
> Disallow: /folder2/
> ```
>
> In this example only the URLs matching `/folder2/` would be disallowed for Googlebot.

Answer (score -2):

If the bots obey the robots.txt file, yes the statement will be visible, so they will not be able to crawl /c.

The wild card (*) after the user agent means all user agents.

However bear in mind not all bots obey robots.txt

Comment: Ok, w.r.t Google, if there is an entry for `User-Agent:Googlebot` and `User-Agent:*` will Google check both sections when crawling ?

Comment: I [don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736338/1591669) think this is correct. `Bot1` and `Bot2` should ignore the last block (`User-Agent: *`).

Comment: @2-Stroker: No, Google will only check the `user-agent: googlebot` section (ie. the "most specific" section), the `user-agent: *` section will be ignored.

Comment: @moobot: "That's what I said." - But you appear to say the complete opposite, which does not seem to be correct?