# Multiple User-agents: * in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Related question: [Multiple User Agents in Robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710324/multiple-user-agents-in-robots-txt)

I'm reading a robots.txt file on a certain website and it seems to be contradictory to me (but I'm not sure).

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blah
Disallow: /bleh
...
... 
...several more Disallows

User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

I know that you can exclude certain robots by specifying multiple User-agents, but this file seems to be saying that all robots are disallowed of a bunch of files but also allowed to access all the files? Or am I reading this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This robots.txt is invalid, as there must only be one record with `User-agent: *`. If we fix it, we have:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blah
Disallow: /bleh
Allow: /
```

`Allow` is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), so not all parsers will understand it (those have to ignore the line).

For parsers that understand `Allow`, this line simply means: allow everything (else). But that is the default anyway, so this robots.txt has the same meaning:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blah
Disallow: /bleh
```

Meaning: Everything is allowed except those URLs whose paths start with `blah` or `bleh`.

If the `Allow` line would come *before* the `Disallow` lines, some parsers [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44063/193139) ignore the `Disallow` lines. But, as `Allow` is not specified, this might be different from parser to parser.

Comment: I thought as much! It definitely seemed weird that there were two 'User-agent: *' records. I'm wondering if I should notify the webmaster of the website that I found it on?